How to merge two tables without common denominator/column in Oracle
How can I combine two tables without common denominator/column at all? This is the sample data:
Table_1

Table_2

Expected Output

Now, I want to combine the two tables and get only the first [5]records from each table.
The condition for Table_1, Sent_Status should be 0.
The condition for Table_2, Unused_status should be 0.
Now if Table_1 will only have 3 records with Sent_Status=0 but Table_2 have [5] records with Unused_status=0, the row count of Table_1 which is 3 should be followed.
Are the two tables possible to combine with the conditions met?
Can someone point me to the right direction?
Thank you in advance!

Assign a row number to the rows for each table and then join on that:
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.email_address,
       t2.color
FROM   (
         SELECT id,
                email_address,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
         FROM   table_1
         WHERE  sent_status = 0
       ) t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT color,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
         FROM   table_2
         WHERE  unused_status = 0
       ) t2
       ON (t1.rn = t2.rn)
ORDER BY COALESCE(t1.rn, t2.rn)
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_1 (id, email_address, sent_status) AS
SELECT 1, 'alice@exmaple.com', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'beryl@exmaple.com', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'carol@exmaple.com', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'debra@exmaple.com', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'emily@exmaple.com', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'fiona@exmaple.com', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'grace@exmaple.com', 0 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_2 (id, color, unused_status) AS
SELECT 100, 'red',    1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 'orange', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 300, 'yellow', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 400, 'green',  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 500, 'blue',   0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 700, 'indigo', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 800, 'violet', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 900, 'black',  0 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID
EMAIL_ADDRESS
COLOR




1
alice@exmaple.com
yellow


2
beryl@exmaple.com
green


3
carol@exmaple.com
blue


4
debra@exmaple.com
indigo


7
fiona@exmaple.com
violet



fiddle

But what if the first table with the conditions only met 2 rows, how will I be able to get only 2 rows from 2nd table?

@Ann Change FULL OUTER JOIN to INNER JOIN.
